# Como trabalhar sem Java.awt.imagem?

Tags: android, ocr

Preciso de uma ajuda sobre uso de OCR em Android, todas as bibliotecas que eu ja tentei usar para converter imagem em Texto precisa ou de um BufferedImage ou de um Renderedimage sendo que ambos estão na biblioteca do Java.awt.image que não esta presente no Android. 
O codigo não tem erro no meu Android Studio mas quando mando compilar da o erro:

```
Error:(111, 57) error: cannot access RenderedImage
class file for java.awt.image.RenderedImage not found
```

Estou usando o OCR da Asprise e ja testei bibliotecas variadas adaptadas do Tesseract ja compiladas para Java mas não funciona.

Alguem tem uma ideia de como poderia contornar isso talvez com o Graphics do Android ou de alguma outra forma, alguma biblioteca de terceiros.

```
String pictureFile = "MinhaFoto_" + date + ".jpg";
String filenameFull = pictureDir.getPath() + File.separator + pictureFile;
File pictureFileFull = new File(filenameFull);

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFileFull);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.close();

    Ocr.setUp(); // one time setup
    ocr = new Ocr(); // create a new OCR engine
    ocr.startEngine("por", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST); // Portugues
    String textoConvertido = ocr.recognize(new File[] {pictureFileFull},
            Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT); // PLAINTEXT | XML | PDF | RTF

    ocr.stopEngine();
```